# How to solve differential equation with integrals in it?

Tags: differential-equations

I have a question.
Is it possible so solve an equation of this type:

$$\frac{dt}{dx} + \sin ^2(t)=-\frac{1}{2} \int_0^x \sin (2 t) \, ds$$

Is it possible to do some iterations to try come close to actual solution?

Answer (score 5):

To get an "analytic" solution, you could differentiate your ODE and use [`DSolveValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DSolveValue). First, use `t[x]` instead of `t` so that the `x` dependence is explicit.

```
ode = t'[x] + Sin[t[x]]^2 == -Integrate[Sin[2 t[s]], {s, 0, x}]/2;
```

Differentiate:

```
dode = D[ode, x];
dode //TeXForm
```

> $t''(x)+2 t'(x) \sin (t(x)) \cos (t(x))=-\frac{1}{2} \sin (2 t(x))$

Use [`DSolveValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DSolveValue):

```
DSolveValue[dode, t, x] //InputForm
```

> Solve::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by Solve, so some solutions may not be found; use Reduce for complete solution information.
>
> Function[{x}, InverseFunction[Integrate[2/(-1 - ProductLog[-E^(-4*C[1] - 2*Cos[K[1]]^2)]), {K[1], 1, #1}] & ][
>     x + C[2]]]

Answer (score 3):

You didn't share complete information, such as, initial condition, the limits on the integral and the "actual solution".

Anyways, here is a way to solve this Integro-Differential Equation,

```
ODE = D[t[x], x] + Sin[t[x]]^2 == -0.5*Integrate[Sin[2*t[s]], {s, 0, x}]

newODE1 = D[t[x], x] + Sin[t[x]]^2 == -0.5*t0[x]

newODE2 = t0'[x] == D[Integrate[Sin[2*t[s]], {s, 0, x}], x]

sol = NDSolve[{newODE1, newODE2, t[0] == 1, t0[0] == 0}, {t[x], 
    t0[x]}, {x, 0, 4}];

Plot[Evaluate[{t[x], t0[x]} /. sol], {x, 0, 4}, PlotRange -> All]
```

Comment: Do you think there is a possibility to solve this analitically, so I get a general solution?